# Ionic 2 saving multiple calendar events

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am currently experiencing a problem with my ionic calendar in that I am able to save input events in an array, retrieve the array and display the info on console. However I am unable to utilize the array and display the array in its original list. I am a noob at ionic:-) so any help will go a long way.

Here is my code so far:

```
//where data is received from a modal and received as(data)    
modal.onDidDismiss(data =>{
      if (data){
        let eventData=data;
        eventData.startTime= new Date(data.startTime);
        eventData.endTime= new Date(data.endTime);

    //initialization of array
```

//this is where the array is displayed

```
        let events=this.eventSource;
        events.push(eventData);
        this.eventSource=[];
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.eventSource=events;
        });
//saving the array of events

        this.storage.set('data1',JSON.stringify(events));
      }

    });
    }

//once view is loaded the saved array should display as before the page is closed.
      ionViewWillEnter() {
        console.log("Showing the first page!");
        this.storage.get('data1').then((data1)=>{

          if(data1){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data1));

            return JSON.parse(data1);

          }



        });
```

Comment: Where and when do you want to show your array?

Comment: Since you are able to save input events in an array, to display this array, use `*ngFor` directive of angular. See about [angular template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). Ionic is build base on angular.

Comment: what do you mean *initialize the array in the list*?

Comment: the array is displayed in the {eventSource=[]} section before the page is reloaded. However on page reload  the array is no longer displayed but it is visible from console storage.get function. I wish to display the array as it was before page reload.Hope this is helpful.

Comment: could you provide me with an example of the ngFo

Comment: Example of ngFor is in the link i provided above. If you are new at Ionic, i strong recomend you take a [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) with angular first. When you complete it, you will understand the basic of angular as same as the basic of Ionic. Then, please take a look at [Ionic Conference App](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app). It is a complete example from Ionic team. I belive you will find out the answer for your question in there.