# Ionic 2 value overwrite

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am having some trouble with my Ionic 2 app. I am currently trying to save multiple values in ionic storage but the save operation seems to be overwriting the value set before hand, resulting in the display of only one object. My code is as follows:

```
 //Receiving data from modal as (data):
modal.onDidDismiss(data =>{
  if (data){
    let eventData=data;
    eventData.startTime= new Date(data.startTime);
    eventData.endTime= new Date(data.endTime);
```

This is where I am trying to save the eventData :

```
 let events=this.eventSource;
    events.push(eventData);
    this.eventSource=[] ;
    setTimeout(() =>{
      this.eventSource=events;
    });

//This is my save operation   

for(var i=0;i<Storage.length;i++){ 
     this.storage.set('data1'+i,JSON.stringify(eventData));
    };
```

And to retrieve the saved data object I did this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log("Showing the first page!");
    for(var i=0;i<Storage.length;i++){
      this.storage.get('data1'+i).then((data)=>{
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      })


    }
```

But console only shows the previously saved object instead of a list of events as I would need. Please help, at this point I am completely stuck

Comment: Why not just save events?

Comment: Which standard of Storage are you using? the Storage interface define **_setItem(key, value)_* and **_getItem(key)_** not *get(key)_ and _set(key,value)_.. you can read this [Storage iterface standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface)

Comment: hi,events is the array that holds all the event objects being passed from modal. Yes i can but the problem i face with this is in retrieving the array and displaying it again on the {eventSource=[]} section. Saving the object is then easier to use.

Comment: hi @rick dana im using the (storage) functionality not (localstorage) but both seem to save only one event object rather than a couple :-( please assist

Comment: @ProfessorAllman i had posted  a similar issue before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924904/ionic-2-saving-multiple-calendar-events?noredirect=1#comment78827516_45924904 please any assistance would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Comment: `storage.set()` returns a promise, so maybe you can get some clue on what's going on by changing the set loop to something like: `this.storage.set('data1'+i,JSON.stringify(eventData)).then(v=>console.log("Correctly set "+v).catch(err=> console.log('Cannot set():'+JSON.stringify(err)) );` . Hope I didn't make a mess with parentheses ;)